# Transformation matrix for polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K= \mathbb{R}$ and $V:= \mathbb{R}[t]_2$ and let $F: \mathbb{R}[t]_2 \to \mathbb{R}[t]_2, f \mapsto f(0)+f(1)\cdot(t+t^2)$.

I want to calculat $M^{S}_{S}(F)$, the transformation Matrix of F with Basis S, being the standardbasis for the polynomialring $S = (1,t,t^2 )$.

So we have to use the coordinate isomorphism:

$M^{S}_{S}(F) = \begin{pmatrix} I_S(F(1)) & I_S(F(t)) & I_S(F(t^2)) \end{pmatrix}$

I already know the solution, however I have no idea why the following matrix is the transformation Matrix of F.

$M^{S}_{S}(F) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Looking at the transformation matrix we know that $F(1)  = 1+t+t^2$ ?
I've never seen anything like this before and I'm really confused. My teacher said this is really easy and now I feel stupid :(

Answer (score 1):

Given a polynomial $f(t) \in V$, $$F(f(t)) = f(0)+f(1)(t+t^2).$$ So, when $f(t)=1$, we have $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and then $F(1) = 1+1(t+t^2) = 1+t+t^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I think I almost got it,$f(t)=t$ we have $f(0)=f(1)=t$? Could you tell me what happens in this case I think it will help me understand it better. I've never seen anything like this before and to me it just seems a weird way of writing a function.

Comment: Given $f(t) = a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2 \in V$ and $\alpha$ a real number, $f(\alpha)$ is just the *evaluation of $f$ at $\alpha$*: $$f(\alpha) = a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2.$$ Note that, in this case, $f(\alpha)$ is another real number, not a polynomial.

Comment: Okay, I think I almost got it. Could you tell me what $F(t)$ or $F(t^2)$ looks like (since they're indentical to calculate). I know that $F(t) = F(t^2) = t+t^2$ since I know the solution (transformation matrix), however I don't see why.

Comment: Hm, so maybe $F(t)=t+t(t+t^2) = t+t^2+t^3$ but since $t^3$ is not in our Field we can just say $F(t) = t+t^2$ same for $F(t^2)=t^2+t^2(t+t^2) = t^2+t^3+t^4$ and this somehow is the same as $t+t^2$ in our field? I don't know I'm lost at this point.